# How can I set up a $.fn. function so it gets executed when called?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
    function init() {
        var $contentButtonPanel: JQuery = $('#content-button-panel')
        $contentButtonPanel
            .find('.arbo .toggle, .collapsible-list li:has(ul) > :first-child, .collapsible-list li:has(ul) > :first-child + span')
            .click(function (event) {
                $(this).toggleBranchOpen();
            });
    }

    $.fn.toggleBranchOpen = function () {
        this.each(function () {
            $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('closed');
        });
        return this;
    };
```

When I debug I can see that the $(this).toggleBranchOpen(); line is reached. However the code does not go inside that function.

Is this a problem with the way that toggleBranchOpen is declared? Note that the only time toggleBranchOpen is used is inside of the init function click event. Is it possible for me to move that code into the init and simplify things?

Comment: Yes, moving it into the handler would simplify much. Especially if it is only needed for that one event, there is absolutely no reason to make it a global function for all jQuery instances.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not go inside that function"? Is it not executed? Do you get errors?

Comment: Replace `var $contentButtonPanel: JQuery = $('#content-button-panel')
        $contentButtonPanel` by just `$('#content-button-panel')`. Looks too much like a Syntax Error

Comment: @Bergi: Sure looks like it. That code doesn't run in FF. It doesn't appear to be a valid syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code:

```
function init() {
    $('#content-button-panel')
        .find('.arbo .toggle, .collapsible-list li:has(ul) > :first-child, .collapsible-list li:has(ul) > :first-child + span')
        .click(function (event) {
            $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('closed');
        });
}
```

Since you indicated that you don't need the global function, I tried to simplify the code a bit.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration is fine. Since you're modifying jQuery's prototype it will be immediately available to all jQuery Objects.

This is the line that is confusing me though,

```
var $contentButtonPanel: JQuery = $('#content-button-panel')
```

I would assume this is just cause you are copying and pasting from a larger file. My only advice as to help identify the problem would be to put some debug information inside this loop;

```
this.each(function () {
    $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('closed');
});
```

Other than that, is it possible that you're selector isn't finding any `li` elements?